# Virtualization hardware

Tags: virtualization

I would like to built a new computer so that it would support server2008 hyper-v role. I can't find any suggestions on hardware configuration (I mean exact part name such as processor model and motherboard model). All what I can find is just recommendations like take a processor with virtualization support, look for motherboard with chipset that supports virtualization. However, there is no guarantee that it going to work as it is suppose to. Can anybody suggest me exact processor and motherboard bundle so that it would support virtualization on 100%. Please no assumptions.

Answer (score 7):

You really need to discuss this with the vendors. It's a constantly changing field and there are numerous configurations that will do the job. The very first thing you need to do is to be able to define exactly what you want the machine to do. e.g. How many virtual machine do you wish to run, using what configurations.

Comment: +1. Speak to your resellers or vendors. If someone here gives you bad advice, you have no recourse. If your vendor gives you bad advice you can take it up with them and tell them "You gave me incorrect info"

Answer (score 0):

you can ask ur reseller for INTEL-VT or AMD-V process it support virtualization..

Comment: There's more to building a system that will support virtualisation properly than buying a processor with a nice little tick in the box for cpu virtualisation features.

Not exactly connected to virtual servers, but have a look at the fuss over Sony laptops and Windows 7's XP mode for a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

Go look at the hardware compatibility lists for the software you want to use.
These are commonly referred to as the HCL. Ask your software vendor/s for it.

Then you can narrow down your hardware shopping list, from the supported systems.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't a fashionable answer but frankly if you want a properly working server for something specific like virtualisation, the simplest answer is to go and buy one "off the peg" from Dell or HP or whoever that has been certified for it. You're not just talking about processor and motherboard, but disk controllers and all kinds of other things that frankly are best left to someone else if you want something that will *definately work*, as you say, as opposed to something "good enough".

Answer (score 0):

For the processor you can look at the Intel Virtualization Technology List [here](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx). Most of the Gigabyte range of motherboard as well as the complete Intel Server Range supports virtualization. However as already mentioned speaking to the vendors is the best way to go.

I have run Hyper-V on a self built Quad Core with a ECS low end board that supported virtualization. We also have it running on a [Dell Optiplex 760](http://www.dell.com/us/en/business/desktops/desktop-optiplex-760/pd.aspx?refid=desktop-optiplex-760&cs=04&s=bsd) and Dell Optiplex 755 at work as well as a [Dell PowerEdge 1950](http://ireland.dell.com/ed/en/business/Servers/pedge_1950_3/pd.aspx?refid=pedge_1950_3&s=bsd&cs=edbsdt1).

Answer (score 0):

You want to purchase servers that are:

- Validated by the [Server Virtualization Validation Program](http://www.windowsservercatalog.com/svvp.aspx)
- Certified by the [Windows Server Logo Certification Program](http://www.windowsservercatalog.com/ready.aspx)

When you send an RFP or ask a vendor for a quote, make sure that you require the solution is validated for those programs. (or other relevant programs) If they provide something that doesn't meet the requirements, you refuse to pay until they make it right.